# Problem installing cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

I have installed wampserver on my pc. I unzipped the cake php installation files in the "www" folder of wampserver. Now, when I try to run- "http://localhost/cakephp", I get a whole list of errors along with the cake php getting started page. Here are some of the errors:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
D:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\libs\inflector.php on line 131

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
D:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\libs\configure.php on line 136

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
D:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\libs\configure.php on line 226

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
D:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\libs\configure.php on line 906
```

How do I fix this? I got similar errors for codeignite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you running ?

To get E_DEPRECATED errors, it must be PHP 5.3 (which is quite recent) -- and I think the last version of WampServer uses this one.

See :

- [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)
- [PHP 5.3.0 Release Announcement](http://fr3.php.net/releases/5_3_0.php)

As it's pretty recent and brought lots of new stuff, you might run into some kind of troubels (you actually did) with PHP 5.3.... Especially if the software you used is not compatible with it yet.

You might want to downgrade to the previous version of WampServer...

Or you could try lowering the [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level (see also [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)), to not get those warnings.

But if you are getting those, you'll probably run into other problems as well...

Actually, after a rapid search into CakePHP's Trac, I found at least those :

- [Ticket #6026 : php 5.3 needs `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/6026)
- [Ticket #6500 : PHP 5.3 incompatibility](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/6500)

None of those is solved... So it seems CakePHP is really not ready for PHP 5.3... *(It's probably not the only Framework in this situation btw -- Zend Framework v 1.9 which went out couple of days ago is the first version that officially supports PHP 5.3, for instance)*

If you want to work with CakePHP, so, you'll probably have to use PHP 5.2.x (like 5.2.9 or 5.2.10).

You're actually [not the only one](http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&client=firefox-a&rls=com.ubuntu%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial&hs=C7I&q=cakephp+%22php+5.3%22&btnG=Rechercher&meta=) in your situation, it seems... Too bad, as there are pretty nice things in PHP 5.3...

Comment: ya..it's PHP 5.3...so, which version of php is supported by cake php?

Comment: Documentation of CackePHP says "PHP 4 or 5" ; I suppose PHP 5.2.x (like 5.2.9 or 5.2.10) would be OK.

Comment: (I just edited my answer with a bit more informations and a couple of links -- too long for just a comment)

Comment: You're welcome :-) Have fun !  (and you might still take a look at PHP 5.3, in a few months, when it's better supported : it has some nice stuff ! )

Answer (score 0):

hi I faced the same problem. I have easyphp installed and the latest easyphp is also using php version 5.3. I downloaded cakephp stable version : Release: 1.2.4.8284 Stable. When i opened the web page, i also got the same 'depricated' notices. I also tried mangling with the 'error_reporting' section with no luck.

As I didn't want to downgrade my php 5.3 to an earlier version, I tried CakePHP 1.3-dev. And the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem.....I downgraded wamp5 2 to wamp 1.6.0...Now its working perfect

Comment: It is possible to implement cake php 1.2 version without downgrading  your wamp server.Just install add-ons for Apache, PHP and MySQL. Click on Wampsever -> PHP->Version->Get More
I have installed different versions of PHP, MySQL and Apache on my wampserver for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I installed the 1.3.0-beta and the problem went away...

e

Answer (score 0):

I tried one solution given by Pascal:
https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/6026
applied this patch and in my case this helped. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem but I got resolve by changing in httpd.conf and php.ini
My changes are here-

**in httpd.conf**
replace

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and in tab Directory "{yourdirectoryname}:/wamp/www/">

replace

```
 Order Deny,Allow 
    Deny from all
```

to

```
 Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
```

in php.ini

make curl ext on. there is no need to run but you should do :)
extension=php_curl.dll

My server and php configuration was
Apache Version : 2.2.17,  PHP Version : 5.3.4