# CakePHP based project is throwing error saying " return value of new by Reference is Deprecated"

Tags: cakephp

I have upgraded my Xampp to newer version(1.7.2).But right now when I run my project(done in CakePHP) it is throwing bug saying

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
C:\xampp\htdocs\ebayn\cake\libs\debugger.php on line 99

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ebayn\cake\libs\debugger.php on line 108

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ebayn\cake\libs\file.php on line 96

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
C:\xampp\htdocs\ebayn\cake\libs\cache\file.php on line 89
```

Can anyone help me how can I rectify this stuff....???

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Solved Problem Plz do not answer.

Comment: Use CakePHP 1.2.5 -> http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/release-cakephp-1-2-5#comment-5021

Comment: For further Assistance go to http://www.phpgeekz.com/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217096/problem-installing-cake-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention your CakePHP version, but if you use PHP 5.3 (which is part of Xampp 1.7.2) then you have to use CakePHP 1.3.x.x.

Comment: Thanks Buddies The Problem Has been solved By Replaceing the Xampp 1.7.2 to Xampp 1.7.1. May be the problem with Newer version of the Xampp.

Answer (score 7):

You need to patch the cake/libs/configure.php and find the line "error_reporting(E_ALL);" replace that line with the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

You may need to change this in your app/webroot/index.php and respectively test.php, too.

There is currently no better way than to touch the core.

Comment: Thanks Buddies The Problem Has been solved By Replaceing the Xampp 1.7.2 to Xampp 1.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included any code, but it looks like you may be attempting to assign a variable by reference - probably an instance of an object. In PHP 5+, that's the default, as I recall. In 5.3, they may have officially deprecated the practice.

If your app has to work with PHP 4, you may want to look at your `error_reporting` setting. If `E_STRICT` is set, turn it off. I don't recall which settings effect which types of errors, but that particular value will probably be instructive if I were to guess.

Comment: Thanks Buddies The Problem Has been solved By Replaceing the Xampp 1.7.2 to Xampp 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to roll PHP 5.3 back to php 5.2 in MAMP in order to run Cake 1.2.

Need to get a local copy of an old client site throwing useful errors, instead of just an Internal Server Error.

Progress...